# transaction error for transaction on multiple databases on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

Is there any reason why my db transaction would work locally on separate DB's but not on QA(Server)?

I get this error on `StudentDatabaseContext.SaveChanges();`

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    try
    {
        StudentDatabaseContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

        SynchronizeLegacyStudent(entity, originalStudentName, originalStudentNumber);
        StudentDatabaseContext.SaveChanges();

        valResponse.Success = true;
        scope.Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        valResponse.Success = false;
        valResponse.SystemErrorMessage = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

exception message:

> The underlying provider failed on Open

inner exception:

> The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction

Here is the Result View:

> Results View = 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'
>   does not contain a definition for 'System' and no extension method
>   'System' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' could be found
>   (are you missing a using ...

Comment: Please check your servers MVC version and see if it matches yours. Also check if all the dlls were deployed properly

Comment: @Thanigainathan The MVC version is the same 4.0.0.1 and its deployed properly as well